# Notepad++ Change random word in a interval

Tags: notepad++

```
"\\DESKTOP-R052I2C\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
"\\DESKTOP-R051I4C\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
"\\DESKTOP-R053I3C\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
```

How i could change the value after R to a unique value?

Above, to:

```
"\\DESKTOP-R111111\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
"\\DESKTOP-R111111\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
"\\DESKTOP-R111111\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
```

If not possible, then, delete everything after `DESKTOP-R`  and before `\Users`.

Resulting:

```
"\\DESKTOP-R\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `DESKTOP-R\K[^\\]+`
- Replace with: `111111`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
DESKTOP-R   # literally
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
[^\\]+      # 1 or more non backslash
```

**Result for given example:**

```
"\\DESKTOP-R111111\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
"\\DESKTOP-R111111\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
"\\DESKTOP-R111111\Users\CAIO\clogs\"
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]